# Django form is_valid() fails

Tags: django, forms, post

I am a real beginner in web development. The following code is failing at the `is_valid()` check. But I do not understand why: The form should get its data filled from the POST-data or not?

Model:

```
class Statement(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateField()
    views = models.IntegerField()
```

ModelForm:

```
class StatementForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Statement
        widgets = {
                   'time':forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'user':forms.HiddenInput(), 
                   'views':forms.HiddenInput(), 
        }
```

View function:

```
def new(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = StatementForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            stmt = form.save()
            path = 'stmt/' + stmt.id
            return render_to_response(path, {'stmt': stmt})
    else:  
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        loggedin_user = request.user 
        d = datetime.now()
        form = StatementForm(request.POST, initial={'time': d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'user':loggedin_user, 'views':0})
        return render_to_response('new_stmt.html', {'form': form, },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I found similar topics and tried a lot. This is how i think it should work. I really need advice.

Comment: Go to earlier questions that you've asked and accept the best answer (if these is one) for a particular question. You can do this by placing the check mark next to an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All fields of your model are required. So, `form.is_valid()` will be True, if all fields are filled with correct values and are not blanked.
You have declared fields `time`, `user`, `views` as hidden fields. Are you sure, that you have filled them in your template form?
Also, you may want to auto stamp field `time = models.DateField()`. Modify your model field like

```
time = models.DateField(auto_now=True)`.
```

After this you don't have to fill it by yourself in template form.

**Your view must return HttpResponse object in all cases**. If your form is not valid, i.e. if `form.is_valid()` will return False, then no `HttpResponse` object will be returned by your view. This can be the source of your fail. Add `else` statement for `if form.is_valid()`:

```
from django.http import Http404
def new(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = StatementForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            stmt = form.save()
            path = 'stmt/' + stmt.id
            return render_to_response(path, {'stmt': stmt})
        else:
            # Do something in case if form is not valid
            raise Http404 
    else: 
        # Your code without changes
```

Comment: Thank you this is clearly an improvement of my code. For my database i need the date in this format: d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"). Would it be possible to initialize the date in the model given a special format like mine?

Comment: When `auto_now` is used for `DateField`, the `datetime.date` object  with current date is passed as value. And when you need to read the `DateField`, you can choose any format you like. Also, as far as i know, `DateField` will store only date, i.e. only this part `%Y-%m-%d`. If you need to store date and time, then you should use `DateTimeField`. Look [DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield).

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
    form = StatementForm(request.POST, initial={'time': d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'user':loggedin_user, 'views':0})
```

For this:

```
    form = StatementForm(initial={'time': d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'user':loggedin_user, 'views':0})
```

Comment: wait, what is the difference between the two? I mean, i can see the Request.POST is missing... but how does that help?

Comment: To answer @bharal - the `new()` method has a conditional. It starts with `if request.method == 'POST': process the data...` then there's an `else` (if the method isn't a `POST`, i.e. if it's a `GET`). If it's not a `POST` method, then why would you include `request.POST` (which wouldn't exist here, after the `else`)?