# django - request.POST missing?

Tags: django, django-forms

So i saw in this answer:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11072057/1061426
```

that someone said:

> Change this line:
>
> ```
> form = StatementForm(request.POST, initial={'time': d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'user':loggedin_user, 'views':0})
> ```
>
> For this:
>
> ```
> form = StatementForm(initial={'time': d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),'user':loggedin_user, 'views':0})
> ```

What is the difference between including the request.POST and not? Or, more to the point - if value X *isn't* set in request.POST, but *is* included in the initial array, what value of X does the is_valid() method see?

EDIT: I guess what i'm asking is ~ which takes precedence in the above? If request.POST and an initial are added, does the initial value overwrite the request.POST value? Is an "empty" value able to be overwritten?
(In the question i relate to, the author was mistakingly using request.POST to seed the StatementForm when the method was a get, which was causing problems for him. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initial` is an argument used to set the initial value of the form at runtime.

Now, `request.POST` is used to bind a form to post data. For example, while submitting a form from browser using `POST` all the relevant fields would be assigned to the `form` object that it can find in `request.POST`

If X is not set in the form, the value is taken from the initial, if present.

You can read up about [initial here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)

Comment: but this doesn't answer the question... I've edited to be clearer!

Comment: form has an attribute has_changed. If something has changed in the POST request, it takes that, if not it takes the initial value, if present. Just try it for yourself. you will know.. It is a really simple concept.