# Django function based form not valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a function based form for taking input from the user to create a customer table. 
I'm using a function based form but when I use `form.is_valid()` it's returning  `False`.

```
def customer(request):
    form = customerForm(request.POST or None )
    print(form)
    context = {'form':form}
    if form.is_valid():
        mobile_no = form.cleaned_data["mobile_no"]
        print("mobile_no")
        object = Customer.objects.get(mobile_no=mobile_no)
        if(object is not None):
            invoice_no = Bill.objects.all().count()
            obj = Bill.objects.create(customer_info=object,invoice_no=invoice_no+1,shop_details=ShopDetail.objects.all())
            return redirect(reverse('receipt:create-bill',kwargs = {'pk':obj.pk}))
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Form invalid</h1>")#redirect(reverse_lazy("home"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django form is\_valid() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071983/django-form-is-valid-fails)

Comment: Post more information (such as your model, your form, and your template) please.

Comment: You can use form.errors to find out why it isn't valid.

Comment: try `print(form.errors)` after your code. then you can see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you sets submiting form method as **GET** but in function set form data by `request.POST`
You must set `method` attribute of html form tag to `post` and change your function as below:

```
def customer(request):
    form = customerForm()
    if request.method.lower() == 'post':
        form = customerForm(request.POST or None )
        print(form)
        context = {'form':form}
        if form.is_valid():
            mobile_no = form.cleaned_data["mobile_no"]
            print("mobile_no")
            object = Customer.objects.get(mobile_no=mobile_no)
            if(object is not None):
                invoice_no = Bill.objects.all().count()
                obj = Bill.objects.create(customer_info=object,invoice_no=invoice_no+1,shop_details=ShopDetail.objects.all())
                return redirect(reverse('receipt:create-bill',kwargs = {'pk':obj.pk}))
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Form invalid</h1>")  # redirect(reverse_lazy("home"))
    return render('my_template.html', context=context)
```