# Not able to save data in database using django form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to save data in database using django form but it not saving it this is my
`forms.py`

```
class PlanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Plans
        fields = ['plan_name', 'plan_note', 'plan_price', 'access_to']
    plan_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput( attrs={
        'class':'form-control',
        'id':'plan_name'
        } ))
    plan_note = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput( attrs={
        'class':'form-control',
        'id':'plan_note'
        } ))
    plan_price = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput( attrs={
        'class':'form-control',
        'id':'plan_price'
        } ))
    can_access = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Add_e_office.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        )
```

and this my `views.py`

```
def add_plan(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PlanForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Plan created successfully.")
            return redirect(request.path)
        return render(request, 'backend/add_plan.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        form = PlanForm()
        return render(request, 'backend/add_plan.html',{'form':form})
```

when i submit my form i receive `POST` request but it did not save data in data base actualy it ignore `form.is_valid()` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072097/14457833 i got a solution user is not in my form fields and i am trying to access it that's why i am not able to save data in my database. After removing user and keeping only `form.is_valid()` is worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `form.errors` while debugging to know what you are stuck with.